# Code Challenge: Rename filenames if duplicates are present

Tags: javascript

I'm working through a coding challenge I found online.  I have the first test case passing but failing the second.  I'm trying to decide if the second test case I'm failing is a typo or not.

Here is the question:

> You are given an array of desired filenames in the order of their
>   creation. Since two files cannot have equal names, the one which comes
>   later will have an addition to its name in a form of (k), where k is
>   the smallest positive integer such that the obtained name is not used
>   yet.
>
> Return an array of names that will be given to the files.

Test Cases:

1 - Passing:

- INPUT: `["doc", "doc", "image", "doc(1)", "doc"]`
- OUTPUT: `["doc", "doc(1)", "image", "doc(1)(1)", "doc(2)"]`

2 - Failing:

- INPUT: `["a(1)","a(6)","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]`
- OUTPUT: `["a(1)","a(6)","a","a(2)","a(3)","a(4)","a(5)","a(7)","a(8)","a(9)","a(10)","a(11)"]`

Here is my code that passes the first Spec:

```
function fileNaming(names) {
    var finalArr = [],
        obj = {};
    names.forEach(function(val){

        if(obj[val] === undefined){
            if(finalArr.indexOf(val) === -1){
              finalArr.push(val);  
              obj[val] = 0;
            } else {
              obj[val] = 1;
              finalArr.push(val + "(" + obj[val] + ")" );
            }

        } else {
            finalArr.push( val + "(" + (++obj[val]) + ")");
        }
    }); 
    return finalArr;
}
```

Question:

- In the second test spec, why isn't there an `"a(1)(1)"` like there is a `"doc(1)(1)"` Is this a typo?
- If anyone has suggestions on improvining my approach or alternative approaches I would greatly appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"a(2)"` instead of `"a(1)(1)"`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think it should be. But if you look at the first example there is a `"doc", "doc(1)", "doc(1)(1)", "doc(2)"`.

Comment: The expected output looks correct. There shouldn't be a a(1)(1) because there doesn't exist a file named a(1) in the array prior to a(1) being encountered in the input. The requirement states the next minimum integer would be used if there exists a duplicate name. Since the next "a" iteration does not have a (1), it would be a(2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simpler approach. The idea is to store both the original and the generated name in the hashtable:

```js
f = function(xs) {
  
  var c = {}, t = (x, n) => x + "(" + n + ")";
  
  return xs.map(function(x) {
    var n = c[x] || 0;
    
    c[x] = n + 1;

    if(!n)
      return x;
    
    while(c[t(x, n)])
      n++;
    
    c[t(x, n)] = 1;
    return t(x, n);
  });

};


q = ["doc", "doc", "image", "doc(1)", "doc", "doc"];
document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(f(q)));

q = ["a(1)","a(6)","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]
document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(f(q)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my approach :

```
def fileNaming(names):
uniq = []
for i in range(len(names)):
    if names[i] not in uniq:
        uniq.append(names[i])
    else:
        k = 1
        while True:
            if (names[i] + "(" + str(k) + ")") in uniq:
                k += 1
            else:
                uniq.append(names[i] + "(" + str(k) + ")")
                break
return uniq
```

Comment: Please explain why/how this answer is better/different from OP.

Answer (score 1):

with arrray approch

```
//var arr=["doc", "doc", "image", "doc(1)", "doc"];
 var arr=["a(1)","a(6)","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"];  

 var arr1=new Array();  
    for (var r in arr)
    {
      if(arr1.indexOf(arr[r])>-1)
      {     
        var ind=1;
        while(arr1.indexOf(arr[r]+'('+ind+')')>-1)
        {
        ind++;      
        }
        var str=arr[r]+'('+ind+')';  
        arr1.push(str);
      }
      else
      {
      arr1.push(arr[r]);
      }
    }
    document.write("INPUT:"+arr+"</br>");
    document.write("OUTPUT:"+arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my beginner approach:

```js
const renameFiles = arr => {
  const fileObj = {};
  let count = 0;
  const renamed = arr.map(currentFile => {
    if (!Object.keys(fileObj).includes(currentFile)) {
      fileObj[currentFile] = count;
      return currentFile;
    } else {
      count++;
      if (Object.keys(fileObj).includes(`${currentFile}(${count})`)) {
        count++;
        return `${currentFile}(${count})`;
      } else return `${currentFile}(${count})`;
    }
  });
  return renamed;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working c++ impl.

```
#include <map>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

string makeName(string n, int i)
{
    string ret = n + "(";
    ret += std::to_string(i);
    ret += ")";
    return ret;
}
std::vector<std::string> fileNaming(std::vector<std::string> names)
{
    map<string, int> lookup;
    vector<string> outNames;
    for (auto name : names)
    {
        auto f = lookup.find(name);
        if (f != lookup.end())
        {
            int index = 1;

            while (lookup.find(makeName(name, index)) != lookup.end())
            {
                index++;
            }
            name = makeName(name, index); // reassign
        }
        lookup[name] = 1;
        outNames.push_back(name);
    }

    return outNames;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is my approach in Javascript:

```
function fileNaming(names) {
    for (i in names) {
        if (names.slice(0,i).includes(names[i])) {
            j = 1
            while (names.slice(0,i).includes(names[i]+"("+j.toString()+")")) {j++}
            names[i] += "(" + j.toString() + ")"}}
    return names
}
```

Comment: Please explain why/how this answer is better/different from Accepted answer by edits.